# Prevent mat-autocomplete from triggering double change detection on keydown

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-changedetection, mat-autocomplete

I am experiencing some performance issues on text input when using mat-autocomplete. Picture one shows the event call tree for a normal input field and picture two shows for a mat-autocomplete field. As seen, the whole change detection sequence is happening double - both for key down and key press when using mat-autocomplete. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I dont need the autocomplete functionality so I have that set to disabled. I just need an input field with the possibility of selecting predefined options.

[Normal input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2aTA.png)
[mat-autocomplete field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW8Rf.png)

I tried using the stopPropagation and stopImmediatePropagation, but does not seem to work.

Comment: they take around 2-3ms - that can not affect your app's performance.